# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.encoder.Encode

Tags: java

I am trying to use the OWASP encoder library in my java class to encode input, but I am not having any luck.  It keeps giving me this

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.encoder.Encode and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/owasp/encoder/Encode

I am including the JAR in the `-classpath` on compilation. Not sure what else to try

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/javac -classpath /path:/path/encoder-1.1.1.jar xxxx.java
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.encoder.Encode
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at xxxxxx.doGet(xxxxxx.java:15)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs that jar present in classpath at runtime as well

run it like

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java -classpath /path:/path/encoder-1.1.1.jar xxxx
```

Comment: how can I add it there?

Comment: please re read my answer, it has `java`

Comment: I understand by the class that uses the encoder is called by a servlet in the form action attribute of an html page so I am not sure how to pass the classpath there

Comment: put jar file  in `WEB-INF/lib` in side your `war` file

Comment: @user1173894 put the external libraries of your web application in `WEB-INF/lib` as stated in the answer of the duplicate question...

Comment: ok I added it there now. do I have to recompile it with the jar under WEB-INF/lib now?

Comment: No, you compiled your source fine, it was missing at runtime, so now retry running your web-app, also for better managed way switch to some proper build tool like maven

Comment: this is painful way of managing library at compilation and at runtime, better to switch to build tool and CI